# publish the Swagger files for external system

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I have integrated swagger with `spring boot`. all is working fine and i am able to access `swagger` document by swagger URL.

> http://www.example.com/swagger-ui.html

some other external system want to `publish` my swagger documentation.

Do `swagger` have any specific file which i can share with external system or any other way?

Comment: https://swagger.io/tools/swaggerhub/ seems a nice way to publish your Swagger docs, if you are trying to make this available to other teams

Comment: What do you mean by "publish"? According to your description your API docs are already published at http://www.example.com/swagger-ui.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the swagger.json from `http://example.com/v2/api-docs` and share that json with external system for publishing it.